# How to join three arrays without "None" in Python 3

Tags: python

I'm trying to loop through three arrays containing lists of words and join them together, space-delimited.

So far, I'm finding that if I use the following for loop:

```
for lines in zip(lines_left, lines_middle, lines_right):
```

I get this result (printed):

`('wage \n', 'forswore \n', 'rake\n')`

My next step is to join them together and cleanup any leading or trailing white space. This is how I am attempting it:

`phrase = print(' '.join(line.strip() for line in lines))`

However, my result (per line) is:

`wage forswore rake None`

How do I join the arrays without "None" on a new line? I tried using `.strip("\n")` as well, to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "result", but you are printing the string `wage forswore rake` to standard output, then assigning the return value of `print` (namely, `None`) to the name `phrase`.

Comment: Don't describe your result; show us the exact code that *produces* that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the result of `print` to `phrase`, but `print` returns `None`. First, assign, then `print` `phrase`:

```
phrase = ' '.join(line.strip() for line in lines)
print(phrase)
```

Comment: You rock. Thanks for that!